# Fusion 360 Simulation Solve Failure

Tags: autodesk

Please help, I simply can't get the simulator to run a static stress test. I get a solve failure error but no indication as to what is causing the failure. I have looked at several things but to no avail. Maybe someone else has ran into this before.

Comment: I have taken some screen shots if that will help...   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7xyBD0Aj42xRkhoR3pPTFlUb3c?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is the error/Result:

593 Tetrahedra :  100.0% of elements (100.0% of volume) 
       Face Angle min:  21.2,  max : 118
       Dihedral Angle min:  7.18,  max : 169
       Worst shape ratio :  10.7  on element 78
       Worst aspect ratio :  3.06  on element 277, 
       Lowest collapse ratio :  0.151  on element 78
       Worst Jacobian ratio :  1  on element 1
Base mesh: 1289 nodes, 593 elements
Solver mesh: 1289 nodes, 593 elements
Job has finished with errors. Receiving results.
Error: Solver Error
Error: An error occurred while solving the model.

Comment: Fusion 360 is CAD software, so I'm not sure how this is related to programming...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled it and the simulation's "Solve" started working.